# Superscript Formatting Erased when Text is stored in String

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Dim ST As String
ST = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
```

In my document, `Paragraphs(1)` is actually **2 + 3<sup>2</sup>**. However, with `Debug.Print ST`, the output is **2 + 32**. Is there any way to store the data without compromising the superscript and subscript formatting?

The objective behind this is to store 5 lines in `ST(1 to 5)` and then shuffle the order of the 5 lines.

Comment: vba strings carry no formatting.

Comment: What alternative would be preferable to fulfil the objective?

Comment: You could store each line of text as AutoText in the attached template. That will retain the Word formatting. Then just shuffle the names of the AutoText entries.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll have a look into that. This might be beyond the scope of this question, however, can you please suggest how I could also include an image that is present in the paragraph along with the formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

1 - It is not clear how do you want to capture the paragraphs so I'm assuming that you will have those paragraphs selected, modify it based on your requirement

2 - It is also not clear on what *shuffle* means so I will assume that you want it to be reversed, you will need to come out with your own logic on how to *shuffle* the paragraphs:

[FormattedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.formattedtext) property can be used to replace a range with formatted text so this should work for you:

```
Private Sub ShuffleSelectedParagraphs()
        
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertParagraphAfter
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Selection.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
        ActiveDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Last.Range.FormattedText = Selection.Paragraphs(i).Range.FormattedText
    Next
End Sub
```

You will need to select the paragraphs first then run the `Sub`, it will duplicate the selected paragraphs at the end of the document but in the reverse order.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to store `ActiveDocument.Content.Paragraphs(1).Range.FormattedText` in a variable? I am currently storing each paragraph in ST(1 to 5) and then I shuffle the array randomly and then overwrite the text in the specific paragraph.

Comment: You can store it in a collection or if the number of paragraphs is fixed (5 fixed `Range`), using array as what you commented seems sufficient in my opinion. @BhaveshShaha